# Deleted ethash - ETH disappeared from Ethereum Wallet

Tags: ethash

I made a mistake and deleted ethash files from my Hard Drive and now my ETH, just 1.96 coins, has disappeared from my Ethereum Wallet. I can see the transaction details and the confirmations on the blockchain. How do I get it back into my Wallet?

Needless to say, I am an idiot.

Comment: Are you using Mist wallet? Is the wallet synced with the network? You usually don't see any balance if the wallet is still syncing.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the `ethash` files and not the `chaindata` files?

Comment: It was ethash data. But, as Mikko said, the wallet (Ethereum Wallet) was still syncing. It showed up after it complete syncing. Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed patience and for my wallet to completely re-sync. Coins reappeared.